# heroku deploy doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

i am deploying my rails app to heroku. after openning my heroku account i tried to 
and downloading the tool belt
login to heroku .

```
  heroku login

Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: my email
Password (typing will be hidden):
!    Unable to connect to Heroku API, please check internet connectivity and 
try again.
```

i saw some answers that talked about the remote option
so i did that:

```
 heroku git:remote -a my-app-name
```

and i got the same response

any idea why and how to fix???

Comment: ensure your tools are up to date with `heroku update`

Comment: i tried but it didn't work i got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your password is correct. Try changing the password in your dashboard and try again.

Comment: its ok but even when i print : heroku update - when it doesn't need a password - it yields the same error.